# NServiceBus Gateway public url

Tags: nservicebus

In my application I have a setup with NServiceBus Gateway on an endpoint and I was able to access it using the url http://localhost/{Endpoint name} from the same machine.

My question is what I have to do to access that endpoint from external machines using the public ip address or domain name.

For e.g. how can I access the gateway endpoint with url http://{My Public ip address}/{Endpoint name}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, what you have to do is simply change the channel address to the domain name you want

```
<GatewayConfig>    
  <Channels>
    <Channel Address="http://{Your domain name}/{Endpoint name}/" ChannelType="Http" Default="true"/>
   </Channels>
</GatewayConfig>
```